# Compositing is not available, please enable compositing support and relaunch Netflix Desktop. WHY?

Tags: netflix, compositing

Compositing is not available, please enable compositing support and relaunch Netflix Desktop.

this keeps popping up and im getting very frustrated. ive reinstalled the enire 12.04 distro, updated everything, followed the directions from eric hoover for installing the patched wine/ netflix app. but every time i go to unity and open the netflix app i get this message. and yes i checked compiz, and compositing is already enabled. please help. thank you in advance.

Comment: i edited the fstab as well as recommended but still get the error.

Comment: no help? so best course of action is to just to go back to windows?

Comment: I had this same problem. this procedure fixed it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/126513#126513

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem pop up recently and after getting all sorts of confused at "answers" I found while trying to remedy the situation (I am by no means a Linux guru), I fixed it by just re-installing the drivers for my graphics card.

I had to first uninstall the old drivers and the new drivers fixed it right up. It now works perfectly.

In my case my card is an older ATI Radeon 3000 HD series and they had a Linux driver available for it.